# Google Sites HTML Box - stripping Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-gadget, google-sites

I am attempting to leverage the new HTML Box Gadget within Google Sites. We are hoping to utilise a `<select>` box as a simple menu to navigate to other pages within our site.

According to the details and example provided by Google (http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2500646) this should be achievable and supported. However, when the page is rendered the Javascript is gone and nothing is functioning. Firebug is not reporting JS issues.

The HTML Box parses fine, with no errors or warnings from the gadget editor.

Code we are using:

```
<style>
  select { font-family: Arial; width: 100px; }
  input { font-family: Arial; }
</style>

<form id="menu-form1" action="">
 <select id="jm1" class="jumpmenu">
     <option value="http://google.com/">Google</option>
     <option value="http://yahoo.com/">Yahoo!</option>
     <option value="http://ask.com/">Ask.com</option>
 </select>
 <input type="button" class="jumpbutton" value="GO" />
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.js"> </script>
<script>
var menuChange = function() {
    var selectBox = $('.jumpmenu');
    alert(selectBox.val());
    window.top.location.href = selectBox.val();
}

$('.jumpmenu').change(menuChange.bind(null));
$('.jumpbutton').click(menuChange.bind(null));

</script>
```

Unless I am doing something "illegal" from a JavaScript point of view, but I don't believe this goes against Googles unsupported features:

- iframes
- JavaScript code can't create any script, image or link tags
- Document/window onload and onready functions. You can place any JavaScript at the end of code that needs to load after the document loads.

Has anyone got anything similar working and can see anything that would cause Google Sites to strip the JavaScript?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

It matters what version of jQuery you are using. Try using version 1.7.2. I loaded your version (1.6) into an example of mine and it stopped working. Using 1.7.2 seemed to work.

Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"> </script>
```

I tried reading through this again - are you asking why the button doesn't launch the actual URL after making a selection?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was simply saving and then shift-refreshing the page.